# Display System class inheritance in UML class diagram(c#)

Tags: c#, uml, diagram, extends

How can I show System class inheritance in a UML class diagram?

Example:

public class MyForm : Form

Form is the System class of c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generalization like this: [image]

or this: [image]

Comment: Class Form is the System.Windows.Forms.Form and when i automatic generate code using this diagram, class Form shouldn't be in my project.